# Datagrid with only 1 row

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a **DataGrid** that will only ever have 1 row of data. It currently displays the first row with data and then 4 empty rows. I don't see a property like *Maximum Number of Rows*. How do I constrict the **DataGrid** to just one row?

Comment: Are you sure your `datasource` is returning 1 row only ?

Comment: Yes, it correctly returns 1 row. I think your concern is that it is returning 1 row with data and 4 rows of empty data, but this is not the case. List.Count is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You constrict the datagrid by limiting the data being given to the datagrid. The datagrid works by displaying whatever data you provide it via the DataSource property.

If the datasource is a Data.DataTable that has 4 empty rows and 1 filled one, then it will display that.

If the DataSource is an array of objects that is predefined to hold 5 elements, then it will display all 5 rows, even if only 1 element is defined.

If the datasource is a SqlDataReader, then you'd limit it by the TOP command in the SQL statement.

I.e. if you want only one row, then have the SQL be something along these lines:

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM tableFoo WHERE SomeRowValue = SomeDataValue ORDER BY SomeRow
```

Basically, depending on the datasource, you'd have different ways of limiting the selection, but it all boils down to only give the grid the rows you want to see.

All that said, there is a way to do this:

1. Turn the DataGrid's Paging on
2. Set the DataGrid's MaxPageSize property to 1
3. (optional) Set the DataGrid's DisplayPagerRow property to false

What this will do is make the datagrid show 1 row at a time. If you had set the MaxPageSize to 2, you'd get two rows.  Turning off the visibility to the Pager Row means that you could not navigate the different pages of the grid.

Comment: Thanks, very good info. Also found that I could set myList.Capacity = 1;